# SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error

Tags: sql-server-2005

Please provide the solution for the error message below

> Msg 824, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect
>   pageid (expected 1:87552775; actual 0:0). It occurred during a read of
>   page (1:87552775) in database ID 7 at offset 0x0000a6fe60e000 in file
>   'D:\DB PGDIP Sum17\dvs.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server
>   error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a
>   severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be
>   corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check
>   (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more
>   information, see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Your database is corrupt, how to fix that is way to broad to answer on any form. Please read up on things like "fix sql server corruption" and update your question to be a lot more specific

Comment: Before doing a full restore, I have sometimes been lucky when a corruption like this takes place in an *index* as opposed to actual *data rows*. If this is the case (`DBCC CHECKDB` should tell you what object the error occurred in), drop the index and then recreate it. If the corruption is in data, you may have to restore.

Answer (score 2):

- Have you read the error message or searched?
- Have you run DBCC CHECKDB to see what is actually wrong?
- have you tried to repair it **WITHOUT DATA LOSS**?
- Do you have a good backup in case repair fails?

Edit

First 2 steps run and backup confirmed

As per [DBCC CHECKDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql), try

```
DBCC CHECKDB (myDB, REPAIR_REBUILD)
```

**Don't** use `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`

Edit 2

As BradC said, it could be something repairable by a quick DROP and CREATE

Comment: • I have searched but didn't get any proper solution.
• I have also run DBCC CHECKDB but issue is not resolved.
• I have not tried to repair.
• I have a good backup in case repair fails.

Comment: As you suggested command DBCC CHECKDB (myDB, REPAIR_REBUILD) i will try but if db size in TB then it will work?

Comment: It might not fix it. And yes it will work in TB size. Is the hardware OK? Disks etc?